# php invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

thanks for looking at this, I am getting this error.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/chris/public_html/marketplace/add_part.processor.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to undefined function error() in /home/chris/public_html/marketplace/add_part.processor.php on line 55
```

Is my code.

```
<?php  

// filename: upload.processor.php

// first let's set some variables

// make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

$uploadsDirectoryThumb = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_file_thumbs/';

// make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'multiple.upload.form.php';

// make a note of the location of the success page
$uploadSuccess = 'parts.php';

// name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
$fieldname = 'file';

//echo'<pre>';print_r($_FILES);exit;



// Now let's deal with the uploaded files

// possible PHP upload errors
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached',
                5 => 'unable to resize image',
                6 => 'error uploading to database');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

// check if any files were uploaded and if 
// so store the active $_FILES array keys
$active_keys = array();
foreach($_FILES[$fieldname]['name'] as $key => $filename)
{
    if(!empty($filename))
    {
        $active_keys[] = $key;
    }
}

// check at least one file was uploaded
count($active_keys)
    or error('No files were uploaded', $uploadForm);

// check for standard uploading errors
foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
    ($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'][$key] == 0)
        or error($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key].': '.$errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error'][$key]], $uploadForm);
}

// check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
    @is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key])
        or error($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key].' not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);
}

// validation... since this is an image upload script we 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
    @getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key])
        or error($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key].' not an image', $uploadForm);
}

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
// not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one
foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
    $now = time();
    while(file_exists($uploadFilename[$key] = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'][$key]))
    {
        $now++;
    }
}

// now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
    @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadFilename[$key])
        or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);
}


function createThumbnail($imageDirectory, $imageName, $thumbDirectory, $thumbWidth, $quality){
    $details = getimagesize("$imageDirectory/$imageName") or die('Please only upload images.');
    $type = preg_replace('@^.+(?<=/)(.+)$@', '$1', $details['mime']);
    eval('$srcImg = imagecreatefrom'.$type.'("$imageDirectory/$imageName");');
    $thumbHeight = $details[1] * ($thumbWidth / $details[0]);
    $thumbImg = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, 
    $details[0], $details[1]);
    eval('image'.$type.'($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName"'.
    (($type=='jpeg')?', $quality':'').');');
    imagedestroy($srcImg);
    imagedestroy($thumbImg);
}

foreach($active_keys as $key)
{
       $tmp_name = $_FILES[$fieldname]["tmp_name"][$key];
       $name = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][$key];
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
       createThumbnail($uploadsDirectory, $name, $uploadsDirectoryThumb, 120, 80);
       //120 = thumb width  ::  80 = thumb quality (1-100)

} 


$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
$part_name = $_POST['part_name'];
$part_qty = $_POST['part_qty'];
$part_price = $_POST['part_price'];
$main_img = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][0];
$part_desc = $_POST['part_desc'];
$extra_1 = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][1];
$extra_2 = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][2];
$extra_3 = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][3];
$extra_4 = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]["name"][4];
$part_loc = $_POST['part_loc'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$date = date("m/d/Y");
mysql_connect(localhost, chris_buyandsell, buyandsell);
mysql_select_db('chris_buyandsell');

$query = "INSERT INTO part (part_name,part_img_main,part_img_more_1,part_img_more_2,part_img_more_3,part_img_more_4,part_cat,part_qty,part_price,part_desc,part_loc,user_id,date_added)";
$query .= " VALUES ('$part_name','$main_img','$extra_1','$extra_2','$extra_3','$extra_4','$cat_id','$part_qty','$part_price','$part_desc','$part_loc','$user_id','$date')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());




// If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved.
// We are now going to redirect the client to the success page.
//header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);
?>
```

Its a giant upload script for images, plus inserting them into the database. 
All my file fields have the correct name assigned as **name="file[ ]"**, I am unsure why its not working.

Comment: Looks like your $_FILES array doesn't exist.

Comment: You have this `//echo'<pre>';print_r($_FILES);exit;`, what is the result if you uncomment it?

Comment: Also, have you created an error function elsewhere that you have not included in this script? That is the cause of the second error.

Answer (score 0):

The error() function is not found, so link you functions controller or right your error function and that should solve your problem.

```
public funtion error($data1, $data2)
{
echo "there was a error\n";

var_dump($data1);

echo "<br />";

var_dump($data2);

}
```

Comment: The issue is, It works on another directory and when I moved it from one directory to another is when it started not working. IT still works in the original testing directoryt it was in.

Comment: you have a php package with error function in it. IF you wnat a quick fix exchange all the error function calls with print_r also write you a simple error dump script